# Basic question: difference between standard least squares mixed model vs generalized linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, anova, glmm, jmp

I'm using jmp for my analysis, and I have data from what is ultimately a mixed model. The problem I have is that JMP doesn't have the ability to run GLMM. You can, however, run a mixed model with a standard least squares personality.

My question is: what am I missing out on by not having the GLMM functionality? What is the difference between what I've done (SLSMM) and a GLMM?

Clarification: response variable is continuous (%growth)

Comment: Can  you please clarify the nature of your response variable?

Comment: @usεr11852 The response variable is continuous (%growth)

Comment: Is it bounded in $[0,1]$ or are there instances where you can have say $100\%+$ or negative growth?

Comment: @usεr11852 I have it in percentages and it ranges from about -26% to 80%

Comment: Hmm... OK. Yes, you are good with treating as a Gaussian (ie. through as LMM). In general if you had relatively small changes (say up to 25%) you could squint and say that that percentage chance can be approximated by change in natural logarithms. (You do not have small changes in the sample you describe.) See [this threa](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136749) too, I think it is very relevant.